# Is there a way to write a JavaScript program that enables you to Search Words in Multiple PDF Files?

Tags: javascript, pdf, full-text-search, ocr, jspdf

I need to create a simple program/system/application using JavaScript that enables a user to search a certain word in multiple scanned PDF files. So basically a user will scan multiple files and save them to the computer as Searchable PDF Files.  Then the user will upload the PDF Files into the program/system/application, that I am trying to create, where he/she will be able to search a certain word in the PDF files that were uploaded.

Basically it's just like the Adobe Acrobat's Advance Search option. I just need to create a similar program but much simpler. It's a project for school. Please help.

JavaScript is my preferred language but if you have any ideas from a different programming language, I'm open to it.

If you can send me links of blogposts or YouTube videos it will be much appreciated.

Thank you so much!

I have already tried this: https://apryse.com/blog/indexed-search/search-multiple-documents-using-javascript but I can't seem to make it work. An error occurs in installing the package. And this is the only thing out there that's very close to what I'm trying to achieve.